# How do I send multiple files over tcp at the same time in c sharp?

Tags: c#, file, tcp, transfer

I have a tcp client - server implementation running in the same program, on different background worker threads. There will be instances of this program on multiple computers so they can send and receive files between each other. I can send files sequentially between computers using network stream, but how would I send multiple files at the same time from computer A to B.

Sending multiple files over one connection ( socket ) is fine, but having multiple network streams sending data to a client, the client doesn't know which chunk of data is apart of which file ?

Would it be possible for the client to connect twice to the server (on a difference port, as a 'random'/ unused port is assigned to the connection) and then each connection have its own stream, allowing 2 files to be sent at the same time?

Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that, but I don't see the benefit.  Unless the each connection is throttled somewhere down the line, you are essentially incurring twice the overhead of your I/O operations.

It's the same as writing a file to a disk, just because you split it to two threads doesn't mean it will be faster, because the disk can only be written to at one time.  You might actually see a *slower* response time.

Comment: Although there maybe a small overhead think of it like this; if i was to send a large'ish file (say 100mb+) to someone on another computer, if i then wanted to send a small text file 
they would have to wait for the large file to finsh before they got the text file, where as if i have multiple connections i could send the small file whilst the large file is also being sent.

I can see what you are saying, the purpose of multiple connections/transfers isn't to speed it up but to allow multiple files to be sent in parallel

Comment: @Metalstorm: If that's the priority, then yes, I agree, this approach is better, just wanted to make sure I pointed it out to you.

Answer (score 5):

The client could certainly connect to the server multiple times - and probably should.

You can specify the same server port though - a different *local* port will be assigned at the server side, but the client doesn't need to know about that. (Think about a web server - *lots* of clients will all connect to port 80 at the same time.)

You'll automatically be assigned separate client side ports as well, of course - basically the connections shouldn't interfere with each other at all.

Comment: Thank you for confirming the multi-connection query.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Asyncronous Client and server sockets. Basically instead of using Recieve and Send, use BeginRecieve, BeginSend, BeginConnect and BeginAccept.  That way the threading is done for you. Having each connection in a worker thread is not a good idea. This way each new request is handled at the same time(asycronously). You can also use the first few bytes of your sent file to store data about the file. Example below. Of course the numbers(1,2,3..) below would be a string filename that you called Bitconverter.GetBytes(String var) on. hope this helps. maxpfc@gmail.com (skype)

```
byte[] completefile = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
byte[] filename;
filename = split(lcomplefile, 3);
```

Below is a compilable example of Asyc Sockets.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class AsyncTcpClient Form:
{
private TextBox newText;
private TextBox conStatus;
private ListBox results;
private Socket client;
private byte[] data = new byte[1024];
private int size = 1024;
public AsyncTcpClient()
{
Text = "Asynchronous TCP Client";
Size = new Size(400, 380);
Label label1 = new Label();
label1.Parent = this;
label1.Text = "Enter text string:";
label1.AutoSize = true;
label1.Location = new Point(10, 30);
newText = new TextBox();
newText.Parent = this;
newText.Size = new Size(200, 2 * Font.Height);
newText.Location = new Point(10, 55);
results = new ListBox();
results.Parent = this;
results.Location = new Point(10, 85);
results.Size = new Size(360, 18 * Font.Height);
Label label2 = new Label();
label2.Parent = this;
label2.Text = "Connection Status:";
label2.AutoSize = true;
label2.Location = new Point(10, 330);
conStatus = new TextBox();
conStatus.Parent = this;
conStatus.Text = "Disconnected";
conStatus.Size = new Size(200, 2 * Font.Height);
conStatus.Location = new Point(110, 325);
This document is created with the unregistered version of CHM2PDF Pilot
Button sendit = new Button();
sendit.Parent = this;
sendit.Text = "Send";
sendit.Location = new Point(220,52);
sendit.Size = new Size(5 * Font.Height, 2 * Font.Height);
sendit.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonSendOnClick);
Button connect = new Button();
connect.Parent = this;
connect.Text = "Connect";
connect.Location = new Point(295, 20);
connect.Size = new Size(6 * Font.Height, 2 * Font.Height);
connect.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonConnectOnClick);
Button discon = new Button();
discon.Parent = this;
discon.Text = "Disconnect";
discon.Location = new Point(295,52);
discon.Size = new Size(6 * Font.Height, 2 * Font.Height);
discon.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonDisconOnClick);
}
void ButtonConnectOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
conStatus.Text = "Connecting...";
Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);
newsock.BeginConnect(iep, new AsyncCallback(Connected), newsock);
}
void ButtonSendOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newText.Text);
newText.Clear();
client.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None,
new AsyncCallback(SendData), client);
}
void ButtonDisconOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
client.Close();
conStatus.Text = "Disconnected";
}
void Connected(IAsyncResult iar)
{
client = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
try
{
client.EndConnect(iar);
conStatus.Text = "Connected to: " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
client.BeginReceive(data, 0, size, SocketFlags.None,
new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), client);
} catch (SocketException)
{
conStatus.Text = "Error connecting";
}
}
void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult iar)
{
Socket remote = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
int recv = remote.EndReceive(iar);
string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
results.Items.Add(stringData);
}
void SendData(IAsyncResult iar)
{
Socket remote = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
int sent = remote.EndSend(iar);
remote.BeginReceive(data, 0, size, SocketFlags.None,
This document is created with the unregistered version of CHM2PDF Pilot
new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), remote);
}
public static void Main()
{
Application.Run(new AsyncTcpClient());
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer "user416134" but this question is rather old. Since then, i've solved by problem (in c#) finished my solution and then moved over to java and implemented it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible for the client to connect twice to the server (on a difference port, as a 'random'/ unused port is assigned to the connection) and then each connection have its own stream, allowing 2 files to be sent at the same time?

Yes; this is how network protocols typically work. You don't need to choose a new port number on the server side: even if you listen on a fixed port number, connections to that port are kept separate.

For instance, the web server at www.stackoverflow.com always listens on port 80, yet you and I can connect from our web browsers, and our connections don't get mixed up.

Comment: Thanks for reinforcing the previous reply, I think this is the route  ill take

Answer (score 0):

You either have to superimpose a protocol on a single socket to identify what data is part of what file, or use multiple sockets so that you know where each file begins and ends.

Even with multiple sockets, you have to have start/end markers if you want to reuse the same socket for a new file without socket open/close housekeeping.

Why can't you use FTP?

Comment: @Steve Townsend

I think for simplicity i will go down the route of  multiple connections, i can see it clearer in my head invisioning each connection being a tunnel/pipe and data being sent down it :)
rather than a  single pipe with lots of start and end bits :)

I understand tcp enough to the point where i can do this (i think), i have only used FTP for local pc - > web -> remote server. Can you ftp over a lan? (im guessing you can) and i don't understand (as in i haven't looked at) the underlying mechanics of ftp

Comment: If you are doing peer to peer xfrs that makes more sense than FTP anyway.  You can always just close the socket and then the receiver knows it has the full file.  It could be worth sending the file length ahead of time, depending on how reliable you need this to be,  and/or use a secure channel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx

Comment: Currently I use this method before sending a file, i send a message comprising of the following COMMAND size filename. Eg BEGINSEND 1024 testfile.zip
so the server knows a file is incoming and runs a function to 'capture' the data for the file. Basically, while(sentData < size)

Comment: Sounds like you are on top of sending some control info to do a little error checking, already then.  The receiver might be able to use this fact to reserve space on disk to optimize the files that get built by interleaved writes a bit.

Comment: I'm about to start work on this now, one further question would each connection (socket) need its own background worker to be able to send data at the same time. Or, bascially whould 
foreach(file in files)
{
socket.BeginSend(...); 
}
work? i think BeginSend acts like a thread in its self?

Comment: You do need multiple threads to get network send parallelism.  Async I/O (as you noted) would work - if you are on .Net 4. you might be able to use Task Parallel Library to make this easier to think about/design.

Comment: Thanks once again for the help, im going to crack on with it :)